# reading file in assets or raw folder in Android

Tags: android, pdf, uri, assets

I have to ship pdf files along with my application and display them as list and when clicked each one should open in Adobe reader. I have tried placing the pdf files in /assets folder also in /res/raw folder. But in either case I am encountering ActivityNotFound Exception. The code and the exception message are below.

**Placing file in /assets/pdf folder**

```
try {
            files = amanager.list("pdf");
            //AssetFileDescriptor fd = amanager.openFd(files[0]);
            Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.csg.android.myproject/assets/pdf/csgsample")  ;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(FirstTab.this, "NO Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Placing file in /res/raw folder**

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.csg.android.myproject/raw/csgsample")  ;
```

Exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.csg.android.myproject/assets/pdf/csgsample typ=application/pdf flg=0x4000000 pkg=com.adobe.reader }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Navin

Answer (score 2):

If you get an `ActivityNotFoundException` is because there are no application to handle that kind of content. So, in that case, I'm sure the the Adobe Reader is installed.

Also, I think you must copy the file to the SDCard for other apps to access it. They cannot access your private data directly for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cristian. When I query the device for all the packages installed using Package Manager, I can see the Adobe Reader in the list. So I am expecting the device to fire the Adobe Reader when it sees this intent. Am I wrong in assuming this? should we explicitly tell the device what package to use for what intent?   I will also think about the second option that you mentioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think assets and raw files are only viewable by your application. 3rd party applications (bundled or not) cannot access these files. You should first put your files in the device's sdcard before opening them.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I should note that this is how I open by resource id

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.csg.android.myproject/" + R.raw.csgsample);
```