# Reading Pdf stored in Raw Folder in android

Tags: android, pdf, directory

I want to put some Pdfs files in Raw Folder in my android application,then reading them using any installed pdf Reader in the Device ...i saw alot of Discussions about this..and many people were asking the same question
But i did not get what i want until now...
in this post they keep answering that assets and raw files are only viewable by the application. 3rd party applications (bundled or not) cannot access these files.
[reading file in assets or raw folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120790/reading-file-in-assets-or-raw-folder-in-android)

and in other posts they suggest to use input and output stream ..then what??
how can i open the pdf...
http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/loading-a-file-from-the-raw-folder-t51145.html

I'm Lost ...
any help please..

Comment: Basically you need to make an outputstream because you would essentially be copying the file, if needed, to the sd card for external storage which would allow third party apps to access it. Just name the file with a .pdf extension.

Comment: "in this post they keep answering that assets and raw files are only viewable by the application" -- this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

File data can be sent as a filename or as a stream (GMail attachments are sent as streams). For the best chance of other applications being able to read the data, it's best to store the file on the SDCard and create a VIEW intent to have another app open it. In the code below, it is assumed that the file is stored with the name in szImageFile:

```
final Intent imageintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
imageintent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + szImageFile), "application/pdf");
startActivity(imageintent);
```