# How to play videos in android from raw folder and htm file

Tags: android, html5-video, local

How can I play videos from a raw folder in an `.htm` file on android?

Neither of these code snippets work for me:

```html
<video id="video" controls>
    <source src="android.resource://tutorials.bodybuilding/raw/smit.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

or

```
<video id="video" controls>
    <source src="url('android.resource://tutorials.bodybuilding/raw/smit.mp4')" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [reading file in assets or raw folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120790/reading-file-in-assets-or-raw-folder-in-android) I guess your addresses are wrong. You should consider what
`Uri.parse("android.resource://tutorials.bodybuilding/" + R.raw.csgsmit);`
returns for every of your videos and place it into html OR at runtime load html into a `String` and replace every address using such method and then load modified html using `Webview.loadData()` or `Webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl()` passing a modified html (a resluting `String`).